# I have a button function in my program. Mostly works, but when I click, it doesn't execute the if. Code included

Tags: javascript, function

```
var rectbutton = function(x,y,width,height,bevel,label,basecolor,textcolor,hovercolor,changevar,changevarvalue){
textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
textSize(height);
fill(basecolor);
rect(x-width/2,y-height/2,width,height,bevel);
fill(textcolor);
text(label,x,y+5);
if(mouseX>=x-width/2 && mouseX<=x+width/2 && mouseY>=y-height/2 && mouseY<=y+height/2){
    fill(hovercolor);
    rect(x-width/2,y-height/2,width,height,bevel);
    fill(textcolor);
    text(label,x,y+5);
    if(mouseIsPressed){
        var changevar=changevarvalue;
    }
}
};
```

Use:
`rectbutton(200,250,250,50,5,"PLAY",color(255,255,255),color(0,0,0),color(255,0,0),playerState,1);`

Everything works until I click. Doesn't set changevar to changevarvalue. Did try `changevar=changevarvalue;` instead of  `var changevar=changevarvalue;`

Answer (score 0):

In your code snipped there is no mouseIsPressed defined anywhere, is it missing? You might need to provide us a more complete code example.

Also try to look at your console if any javascript errors occure.

Answer (score 0):

In js objects are passed by reference and primitives are passed by value. If you want to update your `changevar` variable, you would have to pass an object in changevar parameter while calling the `rectbutton` function and not some primitive value. I'm assuming `playerState` contains some primitive and not an object as a value.